# Changed ownership of entire os to root:root

Tags: arch-linux, root, chown

I had my file/folder ownerships screwed up, so I thought I "restore" them by applying

`chown -Rh root:root /`

and then

`chown -Rh *username*:users /home/*username*`

I did not know that some files are not owned by `root`, so now I can't use sudo and some other services.

Is my os wrecked now or is there a way to restore the ownerships to defaults?
Which files/folders are neither owned by root nor user?

Comment: Your OS is wrecked indeed. Time to reinstall.

Comment: When you `chown` any `suid` file, the `suid` bit is unset.  Hence why `sudo` doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to "refresh" the install of all the system (i.e., in the case of Fedora, ask to `reinstall` all packages), and fix up leftovers (user's home directories, files served e.g. by the webserver) by hand afterwards.

I very much doubt this is substantially less work than doing a clean install, and there will always the lingering doubt of some files with wrong ownership (which, given Murphy's law, *will* bite you in some nasty way at the worst possible moment).

Count it towards the Unix/Linux way learning experience: The system puts *you* in charge, and doesn't try to second guess your orders. If you ask to destroy the system, it will happily comply, no questions asked. With awesome power come high responsibilities.

Comment: I wouldn't trust any system 'fixed' by this method, with anything more important than experimental testing.

Comment: @DonSimon, neither would I. I hope(d) this was clear from my answer...

Comment: On a .rpm system you can potentially restore default ownership and permissions without reinstalling . See - http://www.adminlinux.org/2009/07/how-to-restore-default-system.html or similar

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, thanks, interesting link. But (as DonSimon also says) I wouldn't trust such a "repaired" system to give me the day of the month.

Comment: @vonbrand It works fine on rpm systems (this is one advantage of .rpm)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, I'm a long-time Fedora user myself. I didn't know about those flags to `rpm(8)`, will rummage around it's manpage more. But to repeat, there are just too many files that aren't recorded in rpm's database. To fix *one* package, or even three, I'd look into it. For more, forget it. Better reinstall from scratch.

Comment: @vonbrand - I understand your reluctance, but if you have not tried it you really can not testify it will not work. Try it in a virtual machine if you must ;)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, guaranteeing it will *not* break is to prove a negative, which all know is **notoriously** hard.